# Hiding the modal box

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble with closing a modal box after pressing the restart button. Here is my project:

https://codepen.io/Caysle/pen/aYYKRp

```
//Resets all the progress you've made when you finish the game

function restart() {
    card1 = "";
    card2 = "";
    document.querySelector(".moves").innerText = "0";
    returnStars();

    let cards = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.card'));
    cards = shuffle(cards);
    const deck = document.querySelector(".deck");

    for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        deck.appendChild(cards[i]);
        cards[i].className = "card";
    }

    ready = true;
    stopTimer = true;
}
```

This is the relevant code to restart the progress. All is done except the modal box which doesn't close. What can I do to make it disappear after restarting the progress?

Comment: When using your codepen, I don't have any modal appearing. Do you have to finish the game to get it ?

Comment: Yes you have to. I'd be very appreciated if you do and try to find what is wrong.

Comment: Please simplify your demo to eliminate that requirement.

Comment: Your tags are mismatched in the codepen. If you delete the closing div before the winPage div it works

Comment: From the codepen tag - "_DO NOT use this tag just because your code is hosted on CodePen, and your problem is otherwise unrelated to the CodePen site._"

Comment: @csmckelvey Thanks for the information. I removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move this inside your function restart()

```
document.querySelector(".winPage").className = "winPage closed"
```

Comment: It works. Such a shame not be able to see that. Thank you